# Should i somehow 'publish' my SharePoint site (like in google sites)?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm not really sure how it works.

Why am i asking about that? Because i've just got request that this menu is a bit confusing.

[image: screen]

Comment: There is nothing to publish unless you are working with versioning and content approval.

Comment: @EricAlexander okay then, is it okay if i remove this header from master page? What about guidelines? Is it okay?

Comment: I would not remove it, you lose all the functionality of O365 that way. Look at the Office Dev PnP repo for ideas on how to stylize it in a supported way, https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP.